# Overriding a Magento Action

Tags: php, magento, overriding

There has been many times when all I want to do is override a specific action on a controller but not the whole thing. In most cases I have just overrode the whole controller, but I'm wondering if there is a better way?  Does Magento have a way to just override a single action in a controller leaving the original controller and other actions as they were?

Example:

```
class Mage_Core_AwesomeController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    //has url of awesome/index
    public function indexAction(){
        //Some Awesome code
    }

    //has url of awesome/torewrite
    public function torewriteAction(){
        //Some Awesome code
    }

}

class Local_Core_AwesomeController extends Mage_Core_AwesomeController {

    //has url of awesome/torewrite
    public function torewriteAction(){
        //Some Awesome Override code
    }

}
```

So the url awesome/torewrite would go to Local_Core_AwesomeController but the url awesome/index would go to Mage_Core_AwesomeController.

This example is obviously fabricated, its merely there to show what I would want in theory. So please don't try and correct the example, just demonstrate the best way to override just an action.

I think it would also be important to note that I do not want to rewrite the url, just override the action. Maybe this is impossible without rewriting the url?  Its just that when rewriting the url the tags in the layout change and I would rather keep them the same.

Comment: Supposedly you can do it this way: http://web-magician.blogspot.com/2009/06/overriding-controllers-and-actions-in.html - but this feature seems to be broken. The answer here worked great though, good trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `Local/Core/etc/config.xml`, define your controller within the router to be overridden.

```
<config>
    ...
    <frontend> // Use <admin> for backend routers
        <routers>
            <core> // <-- this is the router name
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <local_core before="Mage_Core">Local_Core</local_core>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </core>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    ...
</config>
```

Magento will now check `Local/Core/controllers` before `Mage/Core/controllers` for URL paths starting with `core` (the router name). Your PHP class above is already correct.

This is only gently hinted at about halfway down [this page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller) where it says:

> Since Magento 1.3 you can simply add your module to the frontend router. Rewrites are not neccessary any more.

Comment: cool i'll give it a try to verify thanks! Just to out of curiosity does this allow you to set a priority chain of sorts... so check local/core/controllers then community/core/controllers then mage/core/controllers? and it will still fire the parent actions correct?

Comment: @sbditto85: I'm pretty sure you'll need to manually call the parent action's with something like parent::indexAction.  Also, since layout rendering gets kicked off in controller actions, you're de-facto stuck doing you're stuff at the top of the controller, and then calling the parent at the end.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question as "it will allow you to fire the parent actions?". Alan is right as usual, you need to call the parent yourself.

Comment: actually i miss-spoke... i meant that the indexAction of the parent class would be called if it wasn't present in the child class...or would i have to override all actions and then have them call parrent::(action)()?

Comment: Since you've extended the core controller normal PHP inheritance applies, you don't need to specify all the actions. If your class didn't descend from the original controller any unspecified actions would still fallback to the original without any further effort on your part.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this. I was fighting with this bug (http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/?issue=10037) for a long time but this works like a charm to override a single action!